# How to tell if a variable is in a nested anonymous structure

Tags: c, doxygen

I am using doxygen to generate metadata about a C structure. However, it seems as though doxygen can't handle nested anonymous structures in its XML output. Take the following struct, for example:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    struct {
        int y;
    } bar;
};
```

From the XML output, it is impossible to tell what is inside `foo` and what is inside `bar` since `x`, `y`, and `bar` are all listed in the XML output as variables inside of `foo`. Is there some option I'm missing?

Comment: This seems to have fixed in [release 1.8.4](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=691071). What version are you using?

Comment: @BlueMoon I'm using `1.8.6` under ubuntu. Also, the problem is that the xml doxygen generates strips out the information about anonymous struct members and hence, from a programatic point of view, it seems as though `x` and `y` are both top level members of `foo`. If the struct is not anonymous, it's not a problem.